# Finding nth permutation in dictionary order with repeats

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a set of symbols (e.g. $(A, A, B, B, B, C, D, D)$), calculate the nth permutation sorted in alphabetical order. I [know how to do this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string) with a set of symbols containing no repeats, but I can't work out how to do it with repeated elements.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can't apply the rule for the $n$th permutation of unique objects in
a cookbook fashion. Instead, go back to first principles.

The number of permutations that start with $A$ is just the number of permutations
of $(A, B, B, B, C, D, D)$.  The number of permutations that start with $B$
is just the number of permutations of $(A, A, B, B, C, D, D)$, and so forth.

Let $Px$ be the number of permutations that start with the subsequence $x.$
The two numbers in the previous paragraph are $P(A)$ and $P(B).$
But $P(A, A)$ is the number of permutations starting with $A,A,$
which is the number of permutations of $(B, B, B, C, D, D),$
and $P(A, B)$ is the number of permutations starting with $A,B.$

To find the first letter, start adding up $P(A),$ $P(B),$ and so forth until the
cumulative sum is at least $n.$

Supposed this shows the first letter is $C.$ Now, starting with $P(A) + P(B)$
(the number of permutations starting with subsequences earlier than $(C)$,)
add $P(B,A),$ $P(B,B),$ and so forth to the total until you have at least $n.$
The point where you stop tells you your second letter.

Unfortunately, $P(A,A) \neq P(A,B),$ for example, so you can't divide $n$ by the 
number of permutations of seven of the letters to find the first letter.
The number of permutations of seven letters depends on *which* seven letters they 
are, which depends on what letter was removed from the set.
There may be a way to make the calculations more convenient than the procedure I laid out
above, but it's not obvious to me.