# Computing the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ permutation of bits.

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string) post about the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ permutation of a set but that is not what I need. If you have a bit string (ones and zeros only) there are [algorithms](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) to quickly permute the NEXT lexicographically ordered bit permutation. For example take $$000111 \rightarrow 001011 \rightarrow 001101\rightarrow\cdots$$ etc. If the string is long then there are going to be approximately one Bajillion of these things. And I want to know how to compute the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ guy without doing the exhaust.

Backgound: This is for a parallel computing job where I need to farm out the search space of elements of a set.

Foreground: I own a copy of Knuth's 4th volume of "The Art of Computer Programming" and I think the answer is in there but I can't seem to find it. (It's like 900 pages).

I'm posting here in the hopes that someone has knowledge of this (obviously). Even if you can point me to a source, say the part in Knuth's book where he describes this problem I would be most grateful.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is in the first 10 pages of Knuth's volume 4: look for grey coding of permutations.

Comment: Why doesn't `000111` go to `001011`?

Comment: If you can compute the _weight_ of your initial bit string (i.e., the number of `1` bits) then you can use the Knuth algorithms for lexicographically ordered combinations - there will be $n\choose w$ of them, of course, where $w$ is the weight and $n$ is the total number of bits.

Comment: Here's a new question with an answer to this question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305375/what-is-the-next-number-having-same-number-of-bit-1

Comment: @EthanBolker, No. Not the same thing. I don't just want the next guy. That is found in my first link.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This recursive algorithm computes the $f(n,m,k)$, the $n$th string of $m$ symbols of which $k$ are ones:

$$f(n,m,k) = \begin{cases}
\epsilon & \text{when }m=0 \\
\mathtt 0.f(n,m-1,k) & \text{when }m\ge1 \text{ and }n\le \binom{m-1}k \\
\mathtt 1.f(n-\binom{m-1}k,m-1,k-1) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Precomputing the binomial coefficients may be useful if you need to do this many times.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out and be sure to understand it, I'll select it as the answer after I get that chance.

Comment: Works beautifully--thanks. I want to be like you when I grow up.

Comment: If I may, I'll try to spell out why this works: Basically, in the first case there is nothing left to do. In the second you CAN put a $0$ in first ( since $n$ satisfies the inequality there) and since we want lexicographically ordered items, we DO put a $0$ in and then we must fill out the rest. Finally we must put a $1$ down, then deal with the consequences as spelled out.

Comment: Beautiful. One important thing to note: that $n\le \binom{m-1}k$ is only suitable when $n$ is indexed from 1. If $n$ is indexed from 0, that test should be $n< \binom{m-1}k$.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are assuming that ${m-1 \choose k} = 0$ when $k>m-1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Every bit string of length $n$ is the binary representation of numbers from $0$ to $2^n-1$. So take theset of integers less than $2^n$ in their natural order and write them out in binary.

Comment: That's what I thought at first. But the OP is looking for the next _permutation_ of the digits, so you can't change the number of 1s. It's not obvious (to me) that there's a straightforward way to add 1 in a loop until you have the same number of 1's and 0's as when you started.